# Как открыть DatePicker по клику на свой элемент?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, office

В [данной](https://dev.office.com/fabric#/components/datepicker) библиотеке дейтпикер открывается по клику на инпут.Однако хотелось бы привязать его к обычной кнопке.Думал в сорсах есть что-то типа `showDataPicker` и можно с помощью `setState`  по клику показывать и прятать его,но тут все рализовано иначе. ПОдскажите пожалуйста как это можно сделать

Comment: `$('#button').click(function(){
$('#datepicker').click();
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал так...

```
constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
        firstDayOfWeek: DayOfWeek.Sunday
    };
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
}
onClick = () => {
    this.datePicker._onTextFieldClick();
}
render() {
    let { firstDayOfWeek } = this.state;

    return (
  <div>
    <DatePicker ref={dp => this.datePicker = dp} firstDayOfWeek={firstDayOfWeek} strings={DayPickerStrings} placeholder="Select a date..."/>
    <button onClick={this.onClick}>Open</button>
  </div>
    );
}
```